# Why does ruby stop me from capitalizing an argument in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I've got a rake task that renames a bunch of stuff in various files.  So, if someone at the cmd terminal writes this

```
 rename:namechange[funk]
```

the code below should perform the necessary find/replace.  My problem is that I can't get this line to work.

```
args[:new_name.capitalize]
```

Any idea why?

```
namespace :rename do

    desc 'changes the name of the app'
    task :changename, :new_name do |task, args| 
      args[:new_name.capitalize]
      # change any instances of the term "framework" to the new name of the app   
      #for testing, just change these: file_names = ['config/environment.rb'] #['config/environments/test.rb', 'config/environments/production.rb', 'config/environment.rb']
      file_names = ['app/helpers/application_helper.rb', 'app/views/pages/home.html.erb', 'rakefile', 'config/application.rb', 'config.ru', 'config/database.yml', 
                    'config/environments/development.rb', 'config/environments/test.rb', 'config/environments/production.rb', 
                    'config/environment.rb', 'config/initializers/secret_token.rb', 'config/initializers/session_store.rb', 'config/routes.rb', 
                    'spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb']
      file_names.each do |file_name|
        text = File.read(file_name)
        File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file << text.gsub("Framework", args[:new_name]) }
      end   
    end     
end
```

UPDATE: I had trouble with ".capitalize" because it automatically put any character after the first as a lowercase letter.  Ultimately, I arrived at this:

```
      args[:new_name][0] =  args[:new_name].capitalize[0]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I edited your title. This is place for adults and professionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to write one of these:

```
args[:new_name].capitalize!
args[:new_name] = args[:new_name].capitalize
```

Answer (score 2):

```
args[:new_name.capitalize]
```

Will just call capitalize on the :new_name symbol returning :New_name and will use that as a key in the args hash. You want to use

```
args[:new_name].capitalize!
```

Which will access :new_name in the args hash and capitalize it in place

Comment: actually, Symbols don't even have a #capitalize method.

Comment: symbols have a #capitalize method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-capitalize

Comment: ah, okay, added in 1.9.x, wasn't there in 1.8.7. Weird, I don't know why you'd ever want to do that to a Symbol